# Why is my font not being picked up by my theme in mui?

Tags: material-ui

I npm installed `@fontsourse/poppins` and added

```css
import '@fontsource/poppins/300.css';
import '@fontsource/poppins/400.css';
import '@fontsource/poppins/500.css';
import '@fontsource/poppins/700.css';
```

to index.css, and in the theme I set the Typography fontFamily to `Poppins` but it is not getting picked up. It only works when I remove the property. Then it renders `Roboto`. Even if I use `Roboto` for the fontFamily property it doesn't work and renders in some default system font. Any idea how to fix this? I am trying to use different fonts on different themes.

```js
export const electraWaveTheme = extendTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
  },
  colorSchemes: {
    light: {
      palette: {
        mode: "light",
        primary: {
          main: "#f0f",
        },
        secondary: {
          main: "#0f0",
        },...
```

The colors work as expected, but I cannot get the font to pick up the installed fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Typography component doesn't use the typography.fontFamily from the theme directly. It uses values derived from it, such as typography.body1.fontFamily.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { experimental_extendTheme as extendTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import '@fontsource/poppins/300.css';
import '@fontsource/poppins/400.css';
import '@fontsource/poppins/500.css';
import '@fontsource/poppins/700.css';

export const electraWaveTheme = extendTheme({
   // your theme
})

electraWaveTheme.typography.fontFamily = 'Poppins';               // <== Add this
```

Source:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30196#issuecomment-993536133

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-scooby-dg452j?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: Thank you so much! The key was importing the css files in the theme. It also works if I import them in where I import the theme provider. This was perfect and solved my problem.